# How to get all edges of two given types (i.e., labels) for a given vertex, only when both edges exist?

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin

For a given vertex, how can we get all the out-edges of two different types (i.e. labels) only when both edge-types exist for that vertex??

For example,

```
g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph();
```

I want to know all those who have *created* some software AND *know* someone. Obviously, I can't use

```
g.V.out('created', 'knows')
```

because, that would give all those who have either *created* something OR *know* someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't set out to solve this in this manner, but using the and() step seems to work well here:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.V.and(_().both("knows"),_().both("created"))
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
```

To get the edges/paths of the vertices that meet the AND criteria, you could do:

```
gremlin> g.V.and(_().both("knows"),_().both("created")).bothE("created","knows").dedup
==>e[9][1-created->3]
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
==>e[10][4-created->5]
==>e[11][4-created->3]
```

Since the first part of the Gremlin gets the vertices that have both "knows" AND "created" edges, you can then safely just grab those edges of both the returned vertices and return the unique ones.

Comment: Thanks, @Stephen! It works alright, however, that returns all the vertices that lie at the head of paths matching this pattern. I would like to return the matching paths as well for `v[1]` and `v[4]`. However, when I use the `path` step at the end of the pattern, it returns only the starting vertices (`v[1]`, `v[4]`). Is it because of the `and` step which only evaluates to `true` or `false` but doesn't not output any elements (vertices or edges)?

Comment: I expanded the answer a bit to return the edges/paths.  I don't know the exact mechanics of and(), but I think your explanation for why 'path' isn't returning what you want is probably a correct assumption.